# show input as it's executed with Rscript

Tags: r, rscript

I have an Rscript that I run using crontab, that take a long time to complete. I'm appending the output of it to a file, and have littered the code with `print` statements to track the progress of the script as it's running in the background.

This works, but I'm getting tired of adding more and more `print` statements. What I really want is to see what command it's running together with the output it generates. E.g. when running the following script:

```
$ cat test.r
#!/bin/env Rscript

Sys.sleep(10)
3+2
```

I'd like the output to somehow be

```
> Sys.sleep(10)
> 3+2
[1] 5
```

i.e. exactly what I'd see had I run it interactively.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to the top of your script:

```
options(echo = TRUE)
```

From `?options`

> echo: logical. Only used in non-interactive mode, when it controls
>   whether input is echoed. Command-line option --slave sets this to
>   FALSE, but otherwise it starts the session as TRUE.